# Flow issue: "required module not found"

Tags: facebook, react-native, babeljs, eslint, flowtype

I am trying to add permissions module in our app, using

> *react-native-permissions@1.0.1*

When i am trying to use it like this:

```
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'
```

During runtime, i got the following error:

```
file: 'file/RunTimePermissionsExample.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'react-native-permissions (Required module not found)'
at: '8,25'
source: 'flow'
```

## Note

- I had gone through these issue's: 
  *https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2092,
  https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3875,
  [Flow required module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130054/flow-required-module-not-found)*
  and tried different methods suggested in them like:

  1. Add this to .flowconfig under options:

     > module.name_mapper='(react-native-permissions)' -> 'empty/object'
  2. Add this to .flowconfig under options

     > module.name_mapper='(react-native-permissions)' -> 
     >   '/flow/GeneralStub.js.flow'
  3. Add this to .flowconfig under [lib]

     declare module 'react-native-permissions' {
      declare module.exports: any;
     }

***Unfortunately, the error is not resolved.***

## Additional Information

- React Native version: ~0.48.4
- React: 16.0.0
- flow-bin: 0.38.0
- eslint: 4.8.0,
- babel-preset-flow: 6.23.0
- Platform: [Android 5.1 and above]
- Development Operating System: [Windows 7 Professional]
- Dev tools: [ Android Studio version 2.3.2, Android SDK 23.1.2]

Comment: Are you ignoring `node_modules`? If so, try `flow-typed` and install a def or create a stub

Comment: Thank you @FezVrasta it was fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some blind hits by rebuild, clean, reinstalling fixed the issue.